# Very slow (stucked) wired connection

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, ethernet, wired

I have both wired and wireless connection on my laptop.
Wired is connected with static IP, while wireless is via dhcp to the same network.
While I can ping, I cannot navigate wired.
This is not a network problem, as the same network configuration is shared with other ips.

Configuration here:
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/24548017/

Wireless ping:

```
    PING www.google.com (216.58.205.132) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mil04s27-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.205.132): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=19.9 ms
64 bytes from mil04s27-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.205.132): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=9.27 ms
64 bytes from mil04s27-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.205.132): icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=12.2 ms
64 bytes from mil04s27-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.205.132): icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=16.8 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 4 received, 20% packet loss, time 4010ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 9.274/14.559/19.925/4.102 ms
```

Wired ping:

```
PING www.google.com (216.58.205.132) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mil04s27-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.205.132): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=6.29 ms
64 bytes from mil04s27-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.205.132): icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=6.40 ms
64 bytes from mil04s27-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.205.132): icmp_seq=7 ttl=52 time=5.47 ms
64 bytes from mil04s27-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.205.132): icmp_seq=8 ttl=52 time=6.17 ms
64 bytes from mil04s27-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.205.132): icmp_seq=12 ttl=52 time=5.39 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 5 received, 58% packet loss, time 15083ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.397/5.949/6.404/0.426 ms
```

while sometimes even:

```
$ ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

Package loss is a lot highter while wired. The percentage can rise up to 70% (maybe more).

I'm using the same configuration from a long time, so I suppose this could be an update issue.

Can you help me please?

Additional infos here: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/24548650/

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Ethernet`, `host www.google.com`, `host www.google.com 8.8.8.8`, and `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX nmcli dev list`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster here you are :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the issue lies in the fact that you have one with static and other with dhcp.  It's my experience that when a laptop is plugged in normally the wireless would disconnect and the Ethernet would take over and vise versa. Does this not happen with your computer?

With having two separate ip addresses working simultaneously to same machine you are confusing your data transmissions possibly.... I bet when your wired your wireless connection does not disconnect.

you can try to ping the ip of the wireless card from another computer on the network while problem machine is wired in and if ping is successful it's still connected when it shouldn't be.

Its going to be hard to tell without looking at your network and the traffic.

I can tell by this:

"while sometimes even:

$ ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com"

may mean your DNS is not working properly. set static DNS to googles 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4 or any DNS servers of your choosing.

Try a traceroute command on wireless and wired post screenshots or data excluding your personal IP www.whatsmyip.com ex: traceroute google.com

(May need to install if not already installed sudo apt-get install traceroute)

while experiencing the issue do a trace route 10 or so times over back to back and see if the first local address stays the same or bounces back and forth between wired and wireless....

disable wireless while on wired see if packet loss goes down.

you can download Wireshark and use a dns filter to see if the dns request are going to the right place. I can greatly help you if I could have 10 minutes of traffic record for wired and wireless so I can see what is actually going on.

But there will be a lot of personal information about your network in those files.

Comment: Genius. What I did now was: reboot, switching off Wireless from  laptop button, and wired connection is stable now. I'll do anyway the tests you suggested, before giving the definitive answer.

Comment: If I connect wireless too now, while wired is up and connected, I can still navigate via wired.  Package loss 0%. I think I reset something strange with a full shoutdown, while before I tried just a few reboots. :/ Edit: It get worst while passing time... I have to disable wifi at all

Comment: Does your ifconfig show local ips for wireless and wired at the same time still or is it auto switching now like it should ? you may need to  manually switch off wireless once on wired with the special hard function switch/button or you can try turning it off in the  graphical settings for networking. Its my experience when taking a windows machine and putting Linux on it some functions may not ever work fully like they should due to the fact that windows has proprietary software and drivers that often get left to generic rebuilds in Linux.